# How to add settings to lightGallery

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightgallery

Im using lightGallery to open a lightbox of images using the solution below, which was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54764289/1390648

Where can I add the settings from the  [lightGallery docs](https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/docs/settings/) to the code below to control the `mode`, `speed`, and other settings?

Each time I try to add them in, it breaks the lightGallery from opening.

```
function initLightGallery() {
    lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
    $("#magic_start").on("click", () => {
        $("#lightgallery :first-child > img").trigger("click");
    });
}
initLightGallery();
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your second line

```
lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
```

by

```
lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'), {
    speed: 500,
    mode: 'fade',
    ...Other settings
});
```

It is right there in the docs ;-)

-> https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/docs/settings/